# (html/css) How do I remove the margin appearing from my header, and have it only apply to my Logo?

Tags: html, css, margin

I am  trying to create a header for my website, with a logo contained. I wish for the logo to have a 5 pixel margin from the top of the header div that it is contained inside, however when I add "margin-top: 5px" to the div containing the logo, the header div is push 5 pixels down instead.

```
<div id="background">
    <div id="HeaderGrey">
        <div id="HeaderLogo">
            <img src="CHBadgeLogo.png" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="HeaderShaderTop"></div>
    <div id="HeaderShaderBottom"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#background  { 
    left: 0px; 
    top: 0px; 
    position: relative; 
    margin-left: auto; 
    margin-right: auto; 
    width: 100%;
    height: 600px; 
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index:0;
    background-color: #303030;
} 
#HeaderGrey {
    background-color: #676767;
    height: 94px;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    margin-top: 0px;
}
#HeaderShaderTop {
    background-color: #0e453d;
    height: 2px;
    width: 100%;
}
#HeaderShaderBottom {
    background-color: #009d89;
    height: 2px;
    width: 100%;
}
#HeaderLogo{
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-left: 28px;
    height: 85px;
    width: 86px;
 }
```

I'm assuming this would have a pretty easy fix, I'm just new to html/css, sorry.

Comment: If you add your html or create a fiddle you will have some answer...

Comment: Can you please provide your `HTML`?

Comment: In addition to your HTML, please consider adding an image or jsFiddle that demonstrates the problem and/or the expected result.

Comment: This is called [margin collapse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin_collapsing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The positioning works only when you put the parent (containing) element as non-static, like relative. Then you can position the element with relative or absolute (taking it out of the flow).

Like so:

```
    body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        position:relative;
    }
    #background  { 
        left: 0px; 
        top: 0px; 
        margin-left: auto; 
        margin-right: auto; 
        width: 100%;
        height: 600px; 
        overflow: hidden;
        z-index:0;
        background-color: #303030;
        position:relative;
    } 
    #HeaderGrey {
        background-color: #676767;
        height: 94px;
        width: 100%;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        margin-top: 0px;
        position: relative;
    }
    #HeaderShaderTop {
        background-color: #0e453d;
        height: 2px;
        width: 100%;
    }
    #HeaderShaderBottom {
        background-color: #009d89;
        height: 2px;
        width: 100%;
    }
    #HeaderLogo{
        margin-top: 5px;
        margin-left: 28px;
        height: 85px;
        width: 86px;
        position: absolute;
     }
```

Comment: This removes the margin at the top of the page, however the logo still fails to have a 5 pixel margin from the top of the header.
http://jsfiddle.net/zzBg6/2/

Comment: You added the padding-top of the #HeaderLogo back in. Get rid of it. Then it works.

Answer (score 0):

Very nice Question,

I see that you know how to use padding which is good. If just simply add a padding-top: 5px; to the image div it should just move the image down 5px from the top of the navbar!

Comment: This removes the margin at the top of the page, however the logo still fails to have a 5 pixel margin from the top of the header.